# Check page outside if using Jquery

Tags: jquery, get

I want to check other websites or pages "REMOTE SERVER like http://www.anywebsite.com" if are using Jquery or not I use this code but don't work !

```
   $.get(url)
   .success(function(data){
    if(data.jquery){
     alert('yes');
    }else{
     alert('no');
    }
   }
```

Comment: you mean url here is REMOTE SERVER!!

Comment: http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2015/10/jquery-check-if-file-exists-with-url-on-remote-server-example.html check this link.. i found a tutorial on it..

Comment: this tutorial for check if url exist or not I need to check if this url using jquery or not